# Is it possible to use Google Web Toolkit functionality in Android?

Tags: android, gwt

Specific situation: I want a package providing a JSON Parser for Android (not self-written, I want to make sure it's maintained and backed by someone). Google has one in [`com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/json/client/package-summary.html).

Is it possible to use this (and other GWT functionality) in Android?

(I know org.json is included in Android, but it has no parsing functionality.)

Comment: What other GWT functionality were you looking for besides JSON parsing?

Comment: @JasonHall Nothing specific, I'm not too familiar with the GWT but I thought it may probably contain some more useful stuff.

Comment: GWT contains a lot of usefull stuff as long zou are deveoping rich web clients running in browser ( it is compiled into javascript  application and executed on client )  -  thus unusabel on android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android SDK includes the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) libraries. You can use them.

```
String json = "{ a: 1 }";
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
int a = jo.getInt("a");
```

If you want something more high-level, you can include the [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) libraries. They work fine under Android.

To answer your question, `com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONParser` is not available under Android.  You won't find anything under com.google.gwt in Android.

Comment: org.json does not include a parser. I'll take a look at the GSON library, thanks. And I know com.google.gwt.* is not available by default, but I was wondering if you could include parts of GWT if you wanted some. But GSON seems a good choice as well.

Comment: yes, org.json does include a parser. it wouldn't be very useful if it did not. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it pure java and does not use some exotic core java classes missing in android it is most probably possible.  And just in case android provides JSON parser  ( in of DOM Mode )
Google GSON is also good and lightweight choice and utilizes pull model.  And you may consider to add some data binding on top of it:

https://github.com/ko5tik/jsonserializer

Comment: a GWT library is not "pure java". GWT compiles to javascript not java bytecode. theoretically, if you had the GWT library source, and the library source only referenced classes that are in the java SDK, you could re-compile the GWT libraries for android.

Comment: I see - this parser makes no sense in java world  but is merely placeholder for JS compiler